# Is there a more functional implementation of this Writable Stream using RxJS that waits for a promise to resolve before processing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, rxjs, stream

I've been living under a rock for a few years so I haven't touched RxJS yet and I'm curious how it handles a situation like below.

The use-case for this is a scenario where I am opening a connection and waiting for it to establish before processing any incoming chunks.

```
const {Readable, Writable} = require('stream')

class DelayedWritable extends Writable {
  constructor(options = {}){
    options.objectMode = true;
    super(options);

    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('...waiting...')
      setTimeout( function() {
        console.log('...promise resolved...')
        resolve(/* with client */)
      }, 2000) 
    }) 
  }
  _write = function(chunk, encoding, done){
    var output = `_write : ${chunk}`
    console.time(output)
    this.promise.then((client) => {
      console.timeEnd(output)
      done() 
    });
  }
  _final = function(done){
    console.log('_final')
  }

}

var readable = Readable.from(['one', 'two', 'three'])
var test = new DelayedWritable();
readable.pipe(test)
```

It seems like a more functional approach would be optimal. RxJS also appears to offer a lot of flow control out of the box, which would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already familiar with Node.js streams, I don't think you'll find it difficult to grasp the same concept in RxJs: *collection of data that comes over time*.

> The use-case for this is a scenario where I am opening a connection and waiting for it to establish before processing any incoming chunks.

This could be translated into RxJs like this:

```js
interval(500)
  .pipe(
    take(5),
    bufferTime(2000), // It takes 2s to establish the connection
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

`$` suffix is used to denote that `src$` is not a simple variable, it is an **observable**(emits values over time).

`interval` will emit values based on the specified time interval and [`bufferTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffertime) will collect the emitted values until the specified `ms` pass. When this happens, you'll get the collected values as an array.

What I particularly like about RxJs is that it comes with a lot of built-in operators that will allow you to manipulate the incoming data.

```js
const src$ = from(['one', 'two', 'tree']);

src$
  .pipe(
    filter(v => v !== 'one'),
    map(v => v.toUpperCase()),
    toArray() // Group the values in an array once the source completes
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-buffer?file=index.ts).

---

Converting a promise to an observable is as simple as:

```js
from(promise).subscribe()
```

---

The above example might seem trivial, and I agree. 
You'll inevitably encounter more complex situations and it will come handy to know about [**higher-order observables**](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/higher-order-observable/).